# Error when trying to pass variables between jobs using artifacts

Tags: gitlab, yaml, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have the fallowing CI parent pipeline and I used artifacts in order to pass variables to a child pipeline:

```
before-script:
  script:
    - terraform --version
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    - export TF_VAR_API_KEY=${TF_VAR_API_KEY}
    - export GIT_TOKEN=${GIT_TOKEN}

prepare-infra-code:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd iac/
    - terraform init -force-copy -backend-config="address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXX/terraform/state/main" -backend-config="lock_address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XX/terraform/state/main/lock" -backend-config="unlock_address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXX/terraform/state/main/lock" -backend-config="username=XXX" -backend-config="password=$GIT_TOKEN" -backend-config="lock_method=POST" -backend-config="unlock_method=DELETE" -backend-config="retry_wait_min=5"
    - terraform plan   
 ...
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd iac/
    - terraform init -force-copy -backend-config="address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXX/terraform/state/main" -backend-config="lock_address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXX/terraform/state/main/lock" -backend-config="unlock_address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXX/terraform/state/main/lock" -backend-config="username=XXX" -backend-config="password=$GIT_TOKEN" -backend-config="lock_method=POST" -backend-config="unlock_method=DELETE" -backend-config="retry_wait_min=5"
    - terraform apply --auto-approve
    - URL=$(terraform output api_url | cut -c2- | sed 's/.$//')
    - S3=$(terraform output bucket_name | cut -c2- | sed 's/.$//')
    - echo "REACT_APP_PORTFOLIO_API=$URL/portfolio" >> deploy-prod.env
    - echo "REACT_APP_TRANSACTION_API=$URL/transaction" >> deploy-prod.env
    - echo "FRONTEND_BUCKET=$S3" >> deploy-prod.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      - dotenv: infra.env
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
jobs:deploy-prod:artifacts reports should be a hash
```

Can someone please help me identify the issue ?

Comment: Remove the `-` from the `dotenv` line. The `-` makes it an array.